# Selenium: Not finding elements with partial selector

Tags: kotlin, selenium-webdriver

I'm having trouble finding a partial "for" element in an Angular page.

Markup:

```
<label for="expense-1-sum"> Future living expenses </label>
```

"Kotlin Selenium code:"

```
var x: WebElement = driver.extendedDriver().findElement(By.ByCssSelector("[for$=expense-]"))
```

This results in the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to  locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[for$=expense-]"}
```

Am I missing the syntax/semantics completely here? It seems to be the exact way I go about finding id's and other tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your locator, `[for$=expense-]`, the `$` means ends with. I'm assuming you meant to use `$` which means starts with, e.g.

```
[for^='expense-']
```

See [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview) for a good syntax reference, explanations, etc.